# Laravel Livewire Select Search Dropdown not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a form in the Laravel Livewire project and try to search and select users from the database. When I search User then search results in users, but nothing to select. Also, no error showing just page refresh. my code is below:
[I'm trying this](https://forum.laravel-livewire.com/t/native-select-search-dropdown-using-livewire/1904)

###### livewire component view

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-2">Select User</label>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 ">
            <div>
                <select wire:model="user_id" class="form-control" name="user_id" required>
                    <option></option>
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                        <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->username}} : {{ $user->fullname }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div style="position:relative">
                <input wire:model.debounce.500ms="inputsearchuser" class="form-control relative" type="text"
                       placeholder="search..."/>
            </div>
            <div style="position:absolute; z-index:100">
                @if(strlen($inputsearchuser)>2)
                    @if(count($searchusers)>0)
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            @foreach($searchusers as $searchuser)
                                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                                    <spanwire:click
                                    ="selectuser({{$searchuser->id}},{{$searchuser->terms}})">{{$searchuser->username}}
                                    : {{$searchuser->fullname}}</span>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                        @endforeach
                    @else
                        <li class="list-group-item">User Not Found...</li>
                    @endif
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

###### livewire component

```php
class MyLiveWireComponent extends Component
{
    public $j = 1;
    public $users = [];

    public $inputsearchuser = '';
    public $user_id;

    public function selectuser($user_id,$terms)
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
$this->terms = $terms;
        $this->inputsearchuser = '';
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $searchusers = [];
        if (strlen($this->inputsearchuser) >= 2) {
            $searchusers = User::Where('username', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->inputsearchuser . '%')
                ->get();
        }
        return view('livewire.admin.orders.add-order', ['searchusers' => $searchusers])->layout('components.layouts.admin');
    }
}
```

Comment: dd($searchusers) after run query retrieve some data?

Comment: yes, I get the search result

Comment: and why don´t achieve that with selec2?

Comment: livewire conflict some select2

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
<spanwire:click="selectuser({{$searchuser->id}},{{$searchuser->terms}})"> 
{{$searchuser->username}} : {{$searchuser->fullname}}
</span>
```

To:

```
<span wire:click.prevent="selectuser({{$searchuser->id}},{{$searchuser->terms}})"> 
{{$searchuser->username}} : {{$searchuser->fullname}}
</span>
```

Comment: sorry, its type of mistake. still not work

Answer (score 0):

Your component should have a single-level root element only. Also, add `wire:key` in your element inside of the loop.

```
      <ul class="list-group">
           @foreach($searchusers as $key => $searchuser)
                <li wire:key="{{'users'.$key}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                    <span wire:click="selectuser({{$searchuser->id}},                        
                    {{$searchuser->terms}})">{{$searchuser->username}}
                    : {{$searchuser->fullname}}</span>
                 </li>
            @endforeach
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you change it to wire:click.prevent as suggested above?  Otherwise, it does not prevent the default action from occurring, and can cause that exact behavior.